# Changing Text Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What I'm trying to do is add a `[+]` or `[-]` sign to an expandable heading so that once the user clicks on the heading, its content part will be shown and its sign part will change from `+` to `-` and vice versa. Since there are multiple headings, I used jQuery's  `next()`. So far the `.content` toggling works well, but for some reason the sign is not changing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".content").hide();

  jQuery(".heading").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").toggle();
    if (jQuery(this).next(".sign").text()=="[+]")
    {jQuery(this).next(".sign").text("[-]");}
    else
    {jQuery(this).next(".sign").text("[+]");}

  });
});
</script>
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
 {
   Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
   NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("Title");
   Element ttl = (Element) title.item(0);
   String linkTitle = getCharacterDataFromElement(ttl);
   htmlReturn += "<a href='#' class='heading'><h4>" + linkTitle + " <span class='sign'>[+]</span></h4></a>";
   htmlReturn += "<div class='content'>";

    ...

}
```

Comment: What does the relevant markup look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the sign is a descendant element of the heading, not a sibling, use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
var sign = jQuery(this).find(".sign");
sign.text(sign.text() === "[+]" ? "[−]" : "[+]");
// Note: A minus sign (−) has the same width as a plus sign (+),
// whereas a hyphen (-) is typically narrower.
```

Comment: Repeating `jQuery(this).find(".sign")` three times is just wasteful. Consider caching it in a local variable.

Comment: @DCoder: Updated and refactored.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (jQuery(".sign").text()=="[+]")
{jQuery(".sign").text("[-]");}
else
{jQuery(".sign").text("[+]");}
```

Comment: Only as long as you have only one `.sign` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `next()` only gets the immediate sibling. Try using `closest()` instead.

Comment: `closest()` finds self or ancenstors, not siblings.